# Activity does not start when called from service when relaunching the app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have a MainActivity which launches a background service. This service monitors the location of the device and if the device is in particular location, It launches another activity LocationBasedActivity which comes to the foreground plays a video, once complete it launches the MainActivity using startActivity.

This works well for the first time when the app is installed. But when the device is restarted and the app is launched, all logic of detecting the location works, but the LocationBasedActivity is not launched. The call to startActivity is being made, but it returns without any error or exception, the following is the code snippet for launching the LocationBasedActivity from the service

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyBackgroundService.this, LocationBasesActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
```

I tried debugging this, got to the point where the call to Android's tried debugging the startActivity which in turn is calling

This is on Android 4.4 on Tab E. Would really appreciate any help on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I can hardly imagine that code executes without error until startActivity() and nothing happens at all. Write a Log.d before startActivity() and one after, and report LogCat output for this case.

Comment: Check your logcat again and make sure that you aren't filtering the logcat. There might be a system error that you are missing if you are filtering.